# How to change background of DataGridCell when IsEditing=True in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, styles, datagridcell

Setting background works fine for `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` but not for `DataGridTextColumn`. I set it for cell in resources:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffff00" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsEditing" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#00ff00" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00ff00" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Which trigger is not working ?

Comment: `IsEditing` is not working only in `DataGridTextColumn `, because it has its own background style in edit mode, I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `magic` string:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
```

in your resources, for example in `<Window.Resources>`.

In this case, when `IsEditing="True"` color is assigned by default (*`White`*), which is taken from the [`SystemColors`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx). But then you need to explicitly set the color for the main panel or for `Window`.

Or set this string in `<DataGrid.Resources>` with `Background="White"`:

```
<DataGrid Background="White" ...>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
        ... 
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Also, the reason this "magic string" is needed is because the text box used by the DataGrid's cells does not take the background as it should. See [Min Zhu's answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e2b803c-975b-450f-a2c5-65cf4327dda3/set-datagridtextcolumn-background-when-in-edit-mode?forum=wpf) to this on the MSDN forums.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is great until it causes side-effects. In my case, it was causing the editing caret to be invisible when editing, probably because setting the "magic" system color was messing with the [logic that sets the caret color automatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2007/02/08/changing-caret-color-in-richtextbox).

A better solution is to simply override the style that the grid uses when it's in edit mode (the `DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle`), like this:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00ff00"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Yet another solution is to make your own `DataGridTemplateColumn`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34158227/63209). This gives you full control over your column, instead of fighting against whatever the built-in `DataGridTextColumn` wants to do. This, however, may be too much power, as it may force you to deal with details you may not want to. But FWIW, it's what worked in my case.