# Disable row edit on WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need help here. I'm trying to disable some rows edit on a WPF DataGrid.
This is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Combustibles}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCombustible}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Value="True" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />                                
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

And this is my ViewModel:

```
public class CombustiblesViewModel: BaseViewModel
{        
    public List<CombustiblesWCFModel> Combustibles{ get; set; }

    private CombustiblesWCFModel _selectedcombustible = new CombustiblesWCFModel();

    public CombustiblesViewModel()
    {
        Combustibles = _svc.Combustibles_List(sTicket);
        Combustibles[1].IsReadOnly = true;
    }            

    public CombustiblesWCFModel SelectedCombustible
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selectedcombustible;
        }

        set
        {
            this._selectedcombustible = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("SelectedCombustible");                
        }
    }
}
```

My Model has a Property:

```
public partial class CombustiblesWCFModel
{
    public Boolean IsReadOnly { get; set; }
}
```

So, Row 1 should be disable for edditing or isn't?

My Finaly boal is to manually start row edit (With a link on each row) and confirm row edit with another link on each row to save data using a WCF services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your columns manually

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=YourField}" 
                    IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadonly}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is actually the answer to so many styling problems with the DataGrid. For example, I wanted to customize cell background, and all I could find were [hacky solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828607/63209) that caused side-effects.
Also: if you do this, know that you will probably want to customize the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your xaml works for me fine.  I would look into your IsReadonly property.  Check for binding expression path errors in your Visual Studio output.